# Error on Bootstrap navbar layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

My navbar should be looking like the one at the top, but instead, it outputs the mess right below it:

[image: .]

How could I fix it?

Here's the code in my html file:

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data- 
     toggle="collapse"
     data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria- 
    controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria- 
   label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current) 
    </span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" 
 role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-
 expanded="false">
      Dropdown
    </a>
   <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
   </div>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Add some code and a jsfiddle would help.

Comment: I'm a beginner, so "add some code" it's pretty vague to me. Any clear example for this occasion? Thanks

Comment: add some code means edit your post and put the code that you have for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was detached and broken, and for main navbar class, it should be

```
navbar-light bg-light
```

not

```
navbar-dark bg-light
```

Please read the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) for how yo can use Bootstrap.

Working navbar example:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```